# Domain of $y=cos^{-1}\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$

Tags: trigonometry

We know that the domain of $y=cos^{-1}x$ is [-1,1], what is the domain of $y=cos^{-1}\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$.

My approach is as follow $-1\le\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\le1$

$\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}-1\le0$ or $\frac{-2x^2}{1+x^2}\le0$

$\frac{-2}{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}\le0$ hence $x\in R$

$0\le1+\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$ or $0\le\frac{2}{1+x^2}$ hence $x\in R$

I would like to know whether my approach is correct

Comment: You should point out that ,when you go from one line to the next, it's "if and only if."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it is not a good idea to divide by $x$; it could be $0$. Anyway, you always have $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\geqslant0$, and so $-\frac{2x^2}{1+x^2}\leqslant0$.

It would be a good idea to add that the answer is $\Bbb R$.